# how to do crud operation in react accordian with api call in backend node js using sequelize

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have 5 Accordions in localhost:3000/management page and each having dynamic values fetching API in backend node Js using Sequelize so how can I show the 5 accordions value in node js????

I want to know for 5 accordion how can I define backend code for one react URL in frontend???

Comment: Please add more details so that we can review your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

On your backend your route should start a function that will return the correct value from your db using Sequelize. I don't know if you're using Express, Fastify etc and you didn't provide code so I won't be able to provide a more detailed explanation but feel free to update your post

On your React frontend you need to fetch from your backend. So that would be something like

```
const data = await fetch("https://yourapiadress...").json()
```

Once you have this you can easily use it in your accordion

```
 data.map(content =>{
  return <Accordion>{content}</Accordion>    
})
```